# rails will_paginate not work with search results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, advanced-search

I'm following the advanced search form revised from railscasts and i'd like to paginate search results but I don't know where put the code for pagination.

I have a model:

mineralisearch.rb

```
    class Mineralisearch < ActiveRecord::Base
        attr_accessible :keywords,:keywords1
        def segnalazione_mineralis
        @segnalazione_mineralis ||= find_segnalazione_mineralis
     end
    private
    def find_segnalazione_mineralis
    segnalazione_mineralis = SegnalazioneMinerali.order(:titolo)
    segnalazione_mineralis = segnalazione_mineralis.where("titolo like ?", "%#
                                                  {keywords}%") if keywords.present?

    segnalazione_mineralis  
    end
    end
```

I have a controller
mineralisearches_controller.rb

```
  class MineralisearchesController < ApplicationController
     def new
     @mineralisearch = Mineralisearch.new
     end

     def create
     @mineralisearch = Mineralisearch.create!(params[:mineralisearch])
     redirect_to @mineralisearch
     end

     def show
     @mineralisearch = Mineralisearch.find(params[:id])

     end
     end
```

and a view

show.html.erb

```
 <h1>Risultati della ricerca</h1>
 <table class="table1">
 <tr>
 <th>Titolo:</th><br>
 <th>Creato il:</th>
 <th>Ultima Modifica il:</th>
 <th></th>
 </tr>
<%= render @mineralisearch.segnalazione_mineralis %>
</table>
```

with this partial
_segnalazione_minerali.html.erb

```
<tr>
<td><%= segnalazione_minerali.titolo %>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>

<td><%= l(segnalazione_minerali.created_at, format:"%e %B %Y %k:%M:%S") %></td>
<td><%= l(segnalazione_minerali.updated_at, format:"%e %B %Y %k:%M:%S")%></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Mostra', [segnalazione_minerali.user, segnalazione_minerali]%></td>
</tr>
```

I know that I must put some code like

```
 @mineralisearch = Mineralisearch.order("Titolo").page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
```

in the controller

and

```
<%= will_paginate @mineralisearch, :previous_label => 'Prec', :next_label => 'Succ' %>
```

but I really don't know where! I tried to put these in the show view and in the controller but they don't work!

Thanks all for help

Answer (score 0):

According to **[will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate)**

This code

```
@mineralisearch = Mineralisearch.order("Titolo").page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
```

should be like this

```
@mineralisearch = Mineralisearch.order("Titolo").paginate(:page => params[:page],:per_page => 10)
```

And you can have this

```
<%= will_paginate @mineralisearch, :previous_label => 'Prec', :next_label => 'Succ' %>
```

in your `show view`.

But it is **`not a normal thing`** to have `pagination` in the `show view` currently which you wants.It is much preferred to have pagination on the `index view`.If you want to have like this,then you have to move the respected controller code snippet to `index action` and the view code snippet to the `index.html.erb` file.

Comment: tnx for the answer..it's only the search show! I need to paginate the show results. I'll try this soultion in a few minutes!

Comment: As I supposed I have this error:
      
          undefined method `segnalazione_minerali' for # <ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Mineralisearch:0x519f
090>

in the show file at 
<%= render @mineralisearch.segnalazione_mineralis %>

Comment: @tettoroberto I guess you have it that line to `<%= render @mineralisearch %>`

Comment: I couldn't change the render beacause it recall the partial that contains the show results! :( I think I must give up :(

Comment: @tettoroberto You should that line to `<%= render :partial => 'segnalazione_minerali' %>` to render a partial `_segnalazione_minerali.html.erb`

Comment: the errror now is : undefined method `total_pages' for #<Vegetalisearch:0x7ee3ee0>

Comment: @tettoroberto That is the different i guess.Has the pagination is working now?

Comment: it's not working! i have undefined method 'total_pages'for #<Vegetalisearch error :( I don't know how can I solve!